# Read lines from file in bash

Tags: bash

For some strange reason, i'm unable to read line by line from a file in bash.
I've always used the classic `while read line; do echo $line; done < file.txt`, but it suddenly stopped working.

Anybody knows if there was an update to bash recently that changed the sintaxis or similar?

Comment: What are the symptoms? "Doesn't work" is very generic.

Comment: `$line` is always empty, is not reading the lines from the file.

Comment: Please provide the version of bash and a sample file.

Comment: 4.3.42, i already googled bugs regarding that version, but found nothing.

The file can be anything, i tested multiple files with random content and it's always the same. Like i said in the question, that line has always worked for me, now it suddenly stopped..

Comment: @Ghost `cat file.txt` please

Comment: Do you really use `while read line` or `while read $line`?

Comment: You might your standard output redirected somewhere odd. Try doing `reset` and re-running (may or may not work depending on what you're running on). Otherwise, just open up another instance

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really provide enough detail to diagnose the problem.  Fair enough, though: you don't know what the problem is so you don't know what's relevant.  Here is a variant command which may address some of the more likely causes or would perhaps shed some light:

```
$ ( unset IFS; while builtin read line; do builtin echo xxx "$line" yyy; done < /etc/motd ) 
xxx  yyy
xxx The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;     yyy
xxx the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the yyy
xxx individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright. yyy
xxx  yyy
xxx Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent yyy
xxx permitted by applicable law. yyy
```

What result do you get from the same command?   The idea here is to check if the `read` or `echo` commands have been turned into aliases or shell functions.   You could also check this with `type echo` and `type read`.